# CSS Background not showing

Tags: css

Hello I made this very simple CSS that should show the background image on a div, and it works on dreamweaver but not on any browsers at all, I really dont know why, was copy and paste from w3 school, where on their example it works on browsers as well here's the code.

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(../img/bottom_line_header.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:bottom;
}
.main_wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
}
.header_button{
    float:right;
    height:60px;
    width:130px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-height:200%;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container" class="main_wrapper">
<div id="container">
<div class="header_button">Contact us</div>
<div class="header_button">Media</div>
<div class="header_button">About us</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

and btw just in case it comes up, the link to the image is correct :D

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML code in your question. You can do this by clicking the `edit` link above.

Comment: an id and class at the same time? `<div id="container" class="main_wrapper">`

Answer (score 1):

You have used the id `container` twice in your HTML. IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting any height, on your `container`, meaning that it's height will be defined by it's content.  In this case, the content is all floated, and floated elements do not contribute to the height of their parent element.

Also, id attributes should be unique on a page, so having two elements with an id of `container` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path is correct:

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    background:url(../img/bottom_line_header.png) bottom no-repeat;
}
```

In this case, you are moving out of the current folder into the `img` folder.

```
-www 
   -css  //say your style sheet is here.
   -img  //your image needs to be here.
```

Make sure `#container` has a height and **an id is unique**, you have 2 elements with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the path is correct...

This

`background-image: url(../img/bottom_line_header.png);`

might need to change to this

`background-image: url(/img/bottom_line_header.png);`

or this

`background-image: url(img/bottom_line_header.png);`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't set the #container width/height  and because u have floating elements in it the height doesn't expand. you have to clear the floats after the header_buttons.

```
     <div style='clear:both'></div>
```

And also the id tag has to be unique for every element.